# How to most easily set the memory capacity of the NSURLCache to zero with AlmofireImage?

Tags: alamofire, alamofireimage

I am using `imageView.af_setImageWithURL(URL)` and it is working great. I am not doing anything with image filters and I saw this note:

> If you do not use image filters, it is advised to set the memory capacity of the NSURLCache to zero to avoid storing the same content in-memory twice.

What is the cleanest/smallest way to accomplish this with the UIImage extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer will certainly work. Here's another approach that doesn't require you to build your own `ImageDownloader`.

```
let downloader = UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader
let configuration = downloader.sessionManager.session.configuration
configuration.URLCache?.memoryCapacity = 0
```

This will end up doing the same thing without having to create any new instances of anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying the following:

```
// From https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage - "If you do not use image filters, it is advised to set the memory capacity of the NSURLCache to zero to avoid storing the same content in-memory twice."
// Note: We're making an educated guess that NSURLCache does not allocate the memory capacity when it's created.. it just uses it as an upper bound. So we'll let ImageDownloader create the session configuration it wants, then we'll just set the memory capacity on its url cache to 0 as suggested.
let configurationWithNoMemoryCapacityOnURLCache = ImageDownloader.defaultURLSessionConfiguration()
configurationWithNoMemoryCapacityOnURLCache.URLCache?.memoryCapacity = 0

UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader = ImageDownloader(
    configuration: configurationWithNoMemoryCapacityOnURLCache
)
```